# Type error: Type 'boolean | (() => void)' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, onclick, next.js

I am trying to play an audio in NextJS app and I am writing code in TypeScript.
My `onClick()` works perfectly fine in dev env meaning when I do `npm run dev`.

```js
<button onClick ={toggle}> {playing ? "Pause" : "Play"</button>
```

but when I am trying to do `npm build` I am getting this error:

> Type error: Type 'boolean | (() => void)' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler | undefined'.
> Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler | undefined'.

After reading a bunch of questions on Stack Overflow, I found out that `onClick()` doesn't expects a void which is what `toggle` function is returning in this case so I did:

```js
<button onClick={() => toggle}> {playing ? "Pause" :"Play</button>
```

After the above change, error of assignment went away but when I ran the app, the play button didn't work anymore.
I am open to any other advice you have for the code.

Here is the full code:

```js
const useAudio = (url: string) => {
  const audio = useRef<HTMLAudioElement | undefined>(
    typeof Audio !== "undefined" ? new Audio(url) : undefined
  );
  
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setPlaying(!playing);
  //const toggle = setPlaying(!playing);

  useEffect(() => {
      playing ? audio.current?.play() : audio.current?.pause();
  }, [playing]);

  useEffect(() => {
    audio.current?.addEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    return () => {
      audio.current?.removeEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    };
  }, []);

  return [playing, toggle];
};

const NFT = ({ baseUri, metaId, url }: { baseUri: string; metaId: string; url: string }) => {
  const [metadata, setMetadata] = useState<{[key: string]: string} | null>(null)

  const fetchMetadata = async (url: string) => {
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const result = await response.json()

    if (!result) return

    setMetadata(result)
  }

  if(url) {
    var [playing, toggle] = useAudio(url);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMetadata(`${baseUri}/${metaId}`)
  }, [])

  if (!metadata) return null

  return (
    <div className="w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3 p-3 mb-4">
      <div className="h-96">
        <div className="relative items-center min-h-full">
          <a href="#">
            <Image
              alt={metadata[MetadataField.Title]}
              src={metadata[MetadataField.Media]}
              layout="fill"
              objectFit="contain"
            />
          </a>
        </div>
         {url &&
          <button onClick ={toggle}> {playing ? "Pause" : "Play"} </button>
         }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Not directly related to your type error but you shouldn't be calling your custom `useAudio` hook conditionally, that goes against the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Answer (score 5):

From the [react-typescript-cheatsheet](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/hooks/#custom-hooks)

> If you are returning an array in your Custom Hook, you will want to avoid type inference as TypeScript will infer a union type (when you actually want different types in each position of the array).

You need to use [const assertions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4/#const-assertions)

```
const useAudio = (url: string) => {
  const audio = useRef<HTMLAudioElement | undefined>(typeof Audio !== 'undefined' ? new Audio(url) : undefined);
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setPlaying(!playing);

  useEffect(() => {
    playing ? audio.current?.play() : audio.current?.pause();
  }, [playing]);

  useEffect(() => {
    audio.current?.addEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    return () => {
      audio.current?.removeEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    };
  }, []);

  return [playing, toggle] as const;
};
```

See below example:

```
function test() {
  return [true, () => {}];
}

const [isOk, func] = test(); 

func();  // error
```

The return type of `test` function is union type `(boolean | (() => void))[]` inferred by TypeScript. When you call `func()`, you will get error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'boolean | (() => void)' are callable.
    Type 'false' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

solution 1: `const assertions`

```
function test() {
  return [true, () => {}] as const
}
```

This will infer to `[boolean, () => void]` instead of `(boolean | (() => void))[]`

solution 2: declare the return type for `test` explicitly

```
function test(): [boolean, () => void] {
  return [true, () => {}];
}
```

Besides, you **CAN NOT** use hooks conditionally, it breaks the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)